# Ionic Native: tried calling Device.uuid, but Cordova is not available

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

I am creating an application and need to get some device data like IMEI, UID, Model and Device Token. All dependency install according to ionicframework documentation.

But I'm facing this error:

> Ionic Native: tried calling Device.uuid, but Cordova is not available.
>   Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator and b) include
>   cordova.js in your index.html

Comment: as suggested are you running your application natively in a device?

Comment: You need to set up and connect a device emulator or your native device to access device info. Here is a link to the docs that explain how to run your app using cordova: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html

Comment: i am facing issue in some devices only that plugin is not installed